# Error 1146 with stored procedure

Tags: mysql

hope everything is going great with you, I'm facing a problem with stored procedure, get to the chase, here's the code :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `register`(in un varchar(45),in pw varchar(45),     

 in user_email varchar(45),
 in permissionid int,in targeted_table varchar(15))
 begin
 declare id int;
 declare target_table varchar(15);
 set target_table = targeted_table;

 insert into user_authentication(user_name,user_password,email,permission_id)
 values(un,pw,user_email,permissionid);

 select user_id into id
 from user_authentication
 where user_name = un;

 insert into target_table(user_id)values(id) ;
 end
```

whenever I call the SP through this statement :

```
  call register('abeer','somePassword','someEmail',1,'job_seeker')
```

workbench shouts at me coming out with this exception :

```
     Error Code: 1146
     Table 'recruitment.target_table' doesn't exist
```

In fact It commits the first insertion statement in the SP, but when It reaches the select statement, I got the exception above, though I'm dead sure the table,job_seeker, is there, can't you just tell me what goes wrong with my SP, for this is the first time using multiple statements inside SP, variables too, thank you .

Comment: Is it possible you're connecting as another user, and that user doesn't have access to that table?  Do you need to do some grants perhaps?  Or are you signed in as "recruitment" but the table exists in another schema?

Answer (score 0):

You have coded a literal for the table name - you want mysql to *evaluate* the variable, *then* execute it as dynamic sql. Here's how you do it:

```
PREPARE mycmd from CONCAT('insert into ', target_table, '(user_id) values(', id, ')');
EXECUTE mycmd;
```

Comment: Have not heard of dynamic sql before, thanks for letting me know it, but the problem is still there, nothing got inserted in job_seeker table,target_table, but I've got a fresh exception instead of the last one, Error Code: 1241
Operand should contain 1 column(s)